# How to disable red screen in debug mode

Tags: react-native

Using `React Native` I would like to keep working in `debug`or `__DEV__` mode but without the red screens.

Does someone know how to disabled it or change `console.error` implementation?

I've tried to do something like this:

```
console.error = {};
```

Or

```
console.error = () => {};
```

But none of the above worked.

Any idea?

Comment: lmao, none of the answers work

Comment: ~3 years later and nothing's changed

Answer (score 27):

Use:

```
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js#L97

Works for me.

Comment: worked for me. Make sure you're pasting it into your main render function.

Comment: How to use It ?

Comment: @Anuj Just place it in your main index.js file.

Comment: Thanks . I just created release build so it is working .

Answer (score 4):

After reading the react-native code I managed to stop the red screen with

`console._errorOriginal = console.error.bind(console);
  console.error = () => {};`

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your app's entry point JS file:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
NativeModules.ExceptionsManager = null;
```

It will disable the native module that's responsible for showing the red-box window (`reportSoftException`, or `reportFatalException` called from `react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js`)

Comment: Thanks master, but it didn't work. My exception throws because of insufficient `NSAssert`

Answer (score 2):

you can try adding

```
 console.error = (error) => error.apply;
```

this will solve your problem

or use

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

if you want to disable warnings

Answer (score 0):

For `iOS`, you can set a preprocessor macro in your `React` Xcode project. If you're using cocoapods, this will be under `Pods (project) -> React (target) -> Build Settings (tab) -> Preprocessor Macros -> Debug`

Set `RCTLOG_REDBOX_LEVEL=4`, where `4` means only redbox for fatal errors.

From `RCTLog.h`:

```
/**
 * Thresholds for logs to display a redbox. You can override these values when debugging
 * in order to tweak the default logging behavior.
 */
#ifndef RCTLOG_REDBOX_LEVEL
#define RCTLOG_REDBOX_LEVEL RCTLogLevelError
#endif
```

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogLevel) {
  RCTLogLevelTrace = 0,
  RCTLogLevelInfo = 1,
  RCTLogLevelWarning = 2,
  RCTLogLevelError = 3,
  RCTLogLevelFatal = 4
};
```

[image]