# React RuntimeError screen

Tags: reactjs

I upgrade react , in newer version , unhanded promise rejection shows as RuntimeError screen

For me , unhanded promise rejection is just a warning and not error, As I have many  warning , that shows as RuntimeError screen , it annoying me in development

How can I disable it for unhanded promise rejection ?

Comment: If it is YellowBox warnings, then you can try : `console.disableYellowBox = true` at any place in your **App.js**. Else, if it is an error, you should probably debug it.

Comment: it is not yellow box , it is red

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to handle and clear the specific error, but if you just want to disable, try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774247/how-to-disable-red-screen-in-debug-mode