# Disable red screen and have actual crash in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I need to get rid of the LogBox screen with the red error while I'm developing React Native in development mode. I should reproduce a real crash (that the app will crash and die), because that red screen is not working for my scenario.

There are several solutions I've tried but they don't work:

1. I can get a real crash in release mode, yes. But I don't want that because I am working on a very specific scenario based on the crash, so I should be reloading and refreshing code too often. For that, I need to be on development mode.
2. `console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;`

   I tried this code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774247/how-to-disable-red-screen-in-debug-mode), but that does not change anything and I'm still having the red screen.
3. `NativeModules.ExceptionsManager = null;`

   I also tried this one again suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774247/how-to-disable-red-screen-in-debug-mode). But that line is causing another error:

   `Unable to put on NativeModules: Operation unsupported`
4. Disabling JS dev mode, disabling refresh or minifying code do not help either.
5. I am working on only Android. Therefore, I tried creating a native module and wrote some erroneous code at the Java part, and triggered that on a button click. At the simplest way, this one:

   ```
   @ReactMethod
   public void crash()
   {
       throw null;
   }
   ```

   But these exceptions are still, caught by the red screen and the are not really crashing the app.

So what I basically need is, simulating a real crash while on development mode. Is there any way to force crash the app in development mode? My react-native version is 0.63.3. Since I am working on only Android, a native solution also works for me. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app in release mode with: react-native run-android --variant=release

In this way you can have your real app in a 'development environment'.