# How do I catch AWS Amplify errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, aws-amplify

If you consider the following code

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentUserInfo()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.username) {
          //do something with data
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('No logged in user'))
  }, [])
```

When I look in my console, I see all this with my console log mixed in.

```
[ERROR] 14:14.682 AuthClass - No current user
at node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Logger/ConsoleLogger.js:115:9 in prototype._log
at node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Logger/ConsoleLogger.js:192:18 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:2097:38 in user.confirmPassword$argument_2.onFailure

No logged in user
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/http:/192.168.50.85:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:949:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1022:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._processRequest (/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:429:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/http:/192.168.50.85:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
}
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/http:/192.168.50.85:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:949:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1022:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._processRequest (/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:429:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/XXXXX/react-native-discord/http:/192.168.50.85:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'
}
```

And I get this on my device
[image]

Neither the `try/catch` or `catch()` seem to catch the error. How can I handle the error better without it blowing up in my console and device?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the stack trace, what is firing the react error screen is a call to `console.error` inside the aws-amplify lib. Try setting [the error reporting from the console.error as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774247/how-to-disable-red-screen-in-debug-mode) in your app entrypoint file.

```
console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;
```

Or upgrade to react-native latest version maybe [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32106) also solves it

By the way, your app should be breaking only on development; in your prod build, react native should ignore it and let you handle the error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, the catch is never triggered with `Auth.currentUserInfo()` so I used `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. The error is now catched like you would expect to happen with currentUserInfo. Weird bug.

```js
try {
  ...Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Auth error', error)
  // Outputs: Auth error The user is not authenticated
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try wrapping the component in an error boundary and handling it with a fallback component. Try using https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary

Comment: This wouldn't be suitable as the code in question isn't necessarily a component, but just a hook within an arbitrary component.